# Adding a clickable margin to UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

So I'm creating multiple `UILabel`s programatically that sits within a `StackView`, and using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to recognise the touches. As of writing, I am using the `StackView`s `spacing` option to give the labels some margin, but I'd like to remove the deadzones given that touches aren't very accurate.

```
stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.alignment = .center
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
stackView.spacing = 12
let recognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.handleGesture))
stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
recognizer.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
stackView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
view.addSubview(stackView)

let label = UILabel()
label.textColor = UIColor.gray
label.textAlignment = .center
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11.0)
label.text = "A"
label.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.15, alpha: 0.8)
label.roundedButton()
stackView.addArrangedSubview(label)
```

`.roundedButton` is an extension like so:

```
extension UILabel {
    func roundedButton(){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

I've tried adding padding with `inset`, but that sits within the background. Any thoughts?

One way of achieving this is by placing the label inside a `UIView`, but there must be a way to do it with just the UILabel

Comment: To answer the incoming comment as a question, the recogniser is added to the stackview, not each label

Comment: Wrap the label in a view, add the recognizer to the view.

Comment: Why are you using labels instead of buttons?

Comment: As far as I have understood you have implemented the logic for longPress recognition but as you are setting stackViews space, a little UI glitch happens as the space doesn't recognise the longPress gesture. Have you tried to create a custom label with altering UIEdgeInsets. With this your space will be maintained and the gesture will also be recognized. Have a look at my answer

Comment: The gesture is recognised as I'm using hitTest to check if the position is within a label, but I want to eliminate the margin and replace it with invisible padding. As far as I can see, UIEdgeInsets adds padding to the inside and doesn't change the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap UILabel inside UIView, and detect touches inside containerView.

```
let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.axis = .vertical
stackView.alignment = .center
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
stackView.spacing = 0
view.addSubview(stackView)

let label = UILabel()
label.textColor = UIColor.gray
label.textAlignment = .center
label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11.0)
label.text = "A"
label.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.15, alpha: 0.8)
label.roundedButton()

let containerView = UIView()
containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(label)
label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: 6).isActive = true
label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor, constant: -6).isActive = true
stackView.addArrangedSubview(containerView)
```

Second solution - subclassing UILabel to add sublayer with shape you need, and setting label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear:

```
class MyLabel: UILabel {

    let subLayer: CALayer = {
        let subLayer = CALayer()
        subLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.15, alpha: 0.8).cgColor
        subLayer.cornerRadius = 6
        subLayer.borderWidth = 1
        return subLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        layer.addSublayer(subLayer)
        subLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:6, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height - 12)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        subLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:6, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height - 12)
    }
}
```

With second solution you should add padding as well probably but that is provided in other answers/comments.

Comment: This is the most logical, but I'm sure there's a way to do it using just the label and the underlying CGLayer?

Comment: Guess you could have label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear, and draw a sublayer with UIColor(white: 0.15, alpha: 0.8) color which is positioned with margins inside UILabel.

Comment: @Nico updated answer with UILabel + CALayer solution

Comment: The second solution looks good! I'll give that a go. I have a feeling I'll need to do something with the border too. Thanks!

Comment: Border should work directly on the sublayer. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I can confirm this does exactly what I was after. I will however provide the end result as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Predag, I was able to achieve exactly what I wanted. Sharing the end result as I added a few helpers for setting background and border.

```
class SuperUILabel : UILabel {
    var spacing: CGFloat = 5

    var subLayer: CALayer! = {
        let subLayer = CALayer()
        subLayer.cornerRadius = 6
        subLayer.borderWidth = 1
        return subLayer
    }()

    func setBorderColor(color: CGColor)
    {
        self.subLayer.borderColor = color
    }

    func setBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {
        self.subLayer.backgroundColor = color.cgColor
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0
        layer.addSublayer(subLayer)
        subLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.spacing / 2, y: self.spacing / 2, width: bounds.width - self.spacing, height: bounds.height)

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        subLayer.frame = CGRect(x: self.spacing / 2, y: self.spacing / 2, width: bounds.width - self.spacing, height: bounds.height - self.spacing)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom label and change the UIEdgeInset as per your requirement(as much space you want to show)

```
class CustomLabel: UILabel {


    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: topInset, left: leftInset, bottom: bottomInset, right: rightInset)
        super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
    }
}
```

Comment: This adds the padding within the background and the border.

Comment: Yes. You needed space and didn't want the dead touches as well. So this may help. May be if you could share your label's UI then I could help more precisely.